# Examples of the "powerful being" and the "attention" they give to an artifact being destroyed by Disjunction

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, lore, artifacts

So I was reading the description of mages disjunction trying to look for a way to make mechanics for rulebreaker from FSN and noticed it said that mages disjunction has a 1% chance per CL to destroy an artifact and that doing so may draw the attention of a "powerful being".

I want to know about examples from pathfinder lore that describe what that powerful being would be and what that "attention" would look like.

> You can also use this spell to target a single item. The item gets a
> Will save at a -5 penalty to avoid being permanently destroyed. Even
> artifacts are subject to mage’s disjunction, though there is only a 1%
> chance per caster level of actually affecting such powerful items. If
> successful, the artifact’s power unravels, and it is destroyed (with
> no save). If an artifact is destroyed, you must make a DC 25 Will save
> or permanently lose all spellcasting abilities. These abilities cannot
> be recovered by mortal magic, not even miracle or wish. Destroying
> artifacts is a dangerous business, and it is 95% likely to attract the
> attention of some powerful being who has an interest in or connection
> with the device.

Comment: There is some part of a phrase missing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You may be cursed, or rewarded, by deity-level beings.

Disjunction comes from D&D's D20 SRD, which in turn is from the D&D *Mordenkainen's Disjunction*. It has had the "attention of a powerful being" clause since its appearance in AD&D 1st edition's *Unearthed Arcana*. The following examples are taken from D&D products, where the spell originates.

#### Cursed, by a deity

The D&D adventure module *Axe of the Dwarvish Lords*, p.9, describes the effect of this spell on the Axe of the Dwarvish Lords:

> In addition, Moradin is 95% likely to visit a curse upon the spellcaster. The curse can have any one of the following effects (DM's choice):

The suggested curses are a disfigurement which weakens the character and makes them hated by all dwarves, an earthquake which surrounds the character whenever they cast a spell (save negates), or an ally's weapon breaks whenever they cast a spell in combat. The only way to remove the curse is to receive an *atonement* from a priest of Moradin, or to do a great service for a deity opposed to Moradin.

Note that even so, the axe only vanishes, but is not destroyed. Page 183 of *Axe of the Dwarvish Lords* asserts that Disjunction can destroy four minor artifacts called the Great Tools, which share the same creator as the *Axe*. No divine backlash is specified for these items.

As per the rules in *Deities and Demigods*, many deities become automatically aware of certain things within their domain, such as artifacts related to them. Destroying an item sacred to Moradin, for example, would very specifically draw Moradin's notice, as may the destruction of artifacts significantly affecting the dwarves. Deities are therefore a prime candidate for noticing Disjunction use.

#### Unspecified harm, by a deity

*Dungeon* magazine #124 adventure *Chambers of Antiquities*, p.87, includes a sarcophagus containing a mummy cleric of Wee Jas. A minor artifact, it can be rendered nonmagical with Disjunction, but doing so would be:

> an act that incurs the wrath of Wee Jas.

The exact penalty is unspecified.

#### Rewarded, by non-specific "powers of good"

*Book of Exalted Deeds*, p.120, suggests that:

> The powers of good smile upon those who rid the world of great evil by destroying a major artifact. A party of good characters who destroys an evil artifact can request a *miracle* at no cost.

It also suggests that destroying an evil artifact while standing within a consecrate or sacred place can help protect against the backlash, although it does not specifically protect against the 95% chance of being noticed by a powerful being.

#### Unspecified danger, by a powerful titan

*Dungeon* magazine #134 adventure *Into the Wormcrawl Fissure*, p.62, describes a lillend who disjuncted a Staff of the Magi ownwed by the titan sorceress Kelastis, and was thereafter forced to flee to the Material Plane to avoid that being's wrath. This is more literal and direct than usual, but it does describe a situation where using the spell invokes a powerful being's attention, because you literally broke a thing they own and now they're angry.

#### Summoning a demon, by Demogorgon

*Dungeon* #147's *Into the Maw*, p.81, describes the affect of using disjunction (or any other means) to destroy an altar to Demogorgon, a demon prince:

> Destroying the altar removes the *forbiddance* and *sympathy* fields, but also immediately alerts Demogorgon, who immediately sends a molydeus demon named Zarvab to investigate. The demon is enraged to discover the condition his master's prison has fallen into, and once he deals with anyone who remains in this area, begins a brutal crusade to cleanse the site of every living thing.

Overall, there seems to be a pattern here. Destroying an artifact commonly angers a deity, demon prince, or similarly powerful being who created, owned, or had a vested interest in that item. However, you may also be rewarded by an equally powerful being who hated the item and wanted it destroyed.